# This mediation group is still serving ads, but there are one or more issues affecting its performance. Expand this mediation group for more details

Tags: admob, facebook-ads-api, mobile-ad-mediation, facebook-ads

After implementing Facebook Ad unity on Admob, I am getting this message in the Mediation Group:

> This mediation group is still serving ads, but there are one or more issues affecting its performance. Expand this mediation group for more details.

[image]

After expanding the mediation group I am getting this message:

`Incorrect mapping`

[image]

I have implemented `GoogleMobileAdsMediationTestSuite` and this is the message I am getting when run it:

[image]

What I need to do to fix this issue?

Comment: Seems the issue in Admob side. Keep in touch with this thread.
https://support.google.com/admob/thread/63557203?hl=en

Comment: Is there update about this issue? @enadun